# How to post radio and checkbox selections? Form handled by php and js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have an Html form that I would like to add radio buttons and checkboxes to but cant seem to get the selections posted the right way. The form is handled by php and js.

Here are the radio buttons and checkbox I would like to add but no matter what I try I can't get it to post the selection.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
     <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
  <div class="row">

  <!-- LINES I WOULD LIKE TO ADD -->
    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <h3 class="section-heading">Choose Options</h3>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="optionsgloss" value="gloss" checked>Glossy
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="optionsnogloss" value="nogloss">Matte
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="optionsRound" value="round">Round Corners
    </label>
  </div>
  <!-- LINES I WOULD LIKE TO ADD -->

<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
       <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
         <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Tell us more." id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
   <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <div id="success"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Send Message</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

What lines would I have to add to PHP:

```
            <?php
    // Check for empty fields
    if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
       empty($_POST['email'])       ||
       empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
       empty($_POST['message']) ||
       !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
       {
        echo "No arguments Provided!";
        return false;
       }

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email_address = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Create the email and send the message
    $to = 'info@email.com'; 
    $email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
    $headers = "From: noreply@email.com\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    return true;            
    ?>
```

And lastly what to add to the js:

```
        $(function() {

        $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
            preventSubmit: true,
            submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
                // additional error messages or events
            },
            submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
                // get values from FORM
                var name = $("input#name").val();
                var email = $("input#email").val();
                var phone = $("input#phone").val();
                var message = $("textarea#message").val();
                var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
                // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
                if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                    firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: "././mail/contact_me3.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        name: name,
                        phone: phone,
                        email: email,
                        message: message
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function() {
                        // Success message
                        $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                            .append("</button>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success')
                            .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success')
                            .append('</div>');

                        //clear all fields
                        $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        // Fail message
                        $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                        $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                            .append("</button>");
                        $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                        $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                        //clear all fields
                        $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                    },
                })
            },
            filter: function() {
                return $(this).is(":visible");
            },
        });

        $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab("show");
        });
    });


    /*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
    $('#name').focus(function() {
        $('#success').html('');
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a form tag in your html code, can you post anything at all ?

Comment: @Shekhar, he's posting with JS, not with the form

Comment: yes the form is working I just cant post new form items because im not entering the right php or js text to post

Comment: That's the start of the form
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio inputs are the same as posting any other input. However, for JS, you need to get the radio value:

```
var selectedOption = $('input[name=options]:checked').val();
```

For checkboxes, it's the same if you only have one...but if you have more than one, you need to build a JavaScript array (assuming checkboxes of `name="checkOptions"`:

```
var checkOptions = [];
$('input[name=checkOptions]:checked').each( function() {
    checkOptions.push($(this).val());
}
```

(there might be some shorter methods for doing it, but that's the general idea.).

I believe in your JavaScript, for the checkboxes, you **MAY?** also need to make the brackets part of the name of the posted value, so:

```
data: {
    name: name,
    phone: phone,
    email: email,
    message: message,
    "option": selectedOption,
    "checkOptions[]" : checkOptions
},
```

In your PHP, it works the same as any other posted data except that $_POST['checkOptions'] will be an array.

Comment: Rather than having to push to a javascript, you can instead just change your input to be `<input type='checkbox' name='choices[]' value='1'>`. This will add all selected checkboxes to an array in the POST.

Comment: @JamesSpence, you mean if Dee uses the `.serialize()` method or something else?

Comment: Nope, no need for any serializing. Just have all your checkboxes have the same name attribute (i.e. 'choices'), place the square [] at the end, and look at POST in php. Should be an array.

Comment: See following [tutorial link](http://davidwalsh.name/checkbox-form-input-arrays) explaining.

Comment: @JamesSpence, that doesn't fit with the OP's code. The OP is using JavaScript to post to web-services NOT using the traditional Post-Back method from the HTML form.  That is why in the JavaScript code, I put the brackets in the name of the posted values...it gets the same result as if you had the `name="checkboxOptions[]"` in a traditional Post-Back setup.  That said, the OP could use the `$('form').serialize()` method to assign all form data...something to the effect of `var data = $('form').serialize()`, but I was trying to go with minimal change to the OP's code.

Comment: Ahh... I see what you're saying now. My bad, I guess I didn't read closely enough. Your solution is about what I'd do too!